# In Java, calling a PostgreSQL function, why I'm getting an error informing that the function doesn't exists?

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, sqlexception

I have this procedure in the database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replacePageRelevance(id INT, value REAL) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO pageRelevance VALUES (id,value);
EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
    UPDATE pageRelevance SET relevance = value WHERE pageId = id;       
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And this code that calls this function:

```
try (CallableStatement cstm = conn.prepareCall(PAGE_RELEVANCE_SQL)) {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Double> entry : weightMap.entrySet()) {
            cstm.setInt(1, entry.getKey());
            cstm.setDouble(2, entry.getValue());
            cstm.addBatch();
        }
        cstm.executeBatch();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error discovering pages relevance: " + e.getNextException());
    }
}
```

This is not working, I'm getting an error informing that *`function replacepagerelevance(integer, double precision) doesn't exists.`*. Why?

The generated call is this: `SELECT replacePageRelevance('882','8.0')`. If I execute this in pgAdmin, it works, but not from Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because your PL/pgSQL function is defined as:

```
replacePageRelevance(id INT, value REAL)
```

[REAL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) is a single precision floating point, but on Java side you're trying to use it as double precision and there is no implicit casting for such situation.

You should rather use [`CallableStatement.setFloat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#setFloat%28java.lang.String,%20float%29) for single precision `REAL` datatype, however it's not co clear, becuase reading Java API:

> Sets the designated parameter to the given Java float value. The
>   driver converts this to an SQL FLOAT value when it sends it to the
>   database.

Since `FLOAT` is a **synonym** for `DOUBLE PRECISION` in Postgres it runs with same effect as [`CallableStatement.setDouble`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#setDouble%28java.lang.String,%20double%29) producing error message (that's weird).

Of course you could just change your function to `replacePageRelevance(id INT, value DOUBLE PRECISION)` and as I checked it works well with your code.

Nevertheless, If you want to keep `REAL` in your function), then use explicit cast like this:

```
String PAGE_RELEVANCE_SQL = "{call replacePageRelevance(?, ?::real)}";
```

Comment: What PostgreSQL type is compatible with double precision?

Comment: @Renato: Just [`double precision`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation. I'm using the conversion now because I don't need much precision